# How to route path to 404 in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Currenlty have a ImageController that catch a route under `/media/upload/` and a IndexController that have a missingMethod() that catch other urls.

But I don't want the IndexController to catch `/media/`-urls

What i had:

```
<?php
Route::get('media/upload/{userId}/{productId}/view/{size}/{filename}',
    'ImageController@anyView');
Route::controllers(['/' => 'IndexController']);
```

tried to add a 404-route using:

```
<?php
Route::get('media/{path?}/{path2?}/{path3?}/{path4?}/{path5?}/{path6?}',
    function() {throw new NotFoundHttpException();});
```

But I if the url has more then 8 '/' then the IndexController catch the URL.

How can I write a route that catch all `media/`-urls (except the one that ImageController use)?

Comment: You mention 8 `/` but your media route only listens for requests with 6 path segments

Comment: yes, 8 is larger then 6, urls with 10 / dosn't get catched either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically if you want `media*` to be caught then do:

```
Route::get('media/upload/{userId}/{productId}/view/{size}/{filename}',
'ImageController@anyView');
 Route::get("media/{param?}", function ($param) {
       throw new NotFoundHttpException();
 })->where("param",".*")
 Route::controllers(['/' => 'IndexController']);
```

That should catch everything after media and put it into `$param` in your route handler. Ideally anything that matches the first route will not be caught by the second and then anything that matches /media* will not be caught by index.

However the order is important.

Comment: just found that soultion to, from `\Illuminate\Routing\Router::addFallthroughRoute()`, worked fine.

Comment: `addFallthroughRoute` seems to also be the cause of your problems because `Route::controller` seems to add a fallthough for all parameters after the url e.g. in your case `/{anything}` . Just as a sidenote: the framework recommendation is to be explicit with route names and not wildcard them. That way the framework can correctly determine what's a 404. Also `Route::controller` is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will have to write the route that you want to catch in the ImageController above the other one in api.php file. Now the best approach to do this can to group your both of the routes in a CustomMiddleware that you can create using the command

`php artisan make:middleware MyMiddleware`

Now use this middleware to check the number of **/** and the pass the request or throw an exception as per your requirement.